# Please identify the sub assemblies

Tags: set-identification

Can you please identify the sub assemblies from the pictures. Is this part of a set or something someone just build? As you can see there are a lot of missing pieces. Do they ring a bell to anyone?

**(A)**

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**(B)**

[image]

[image]

---

**(C)**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please ignore sub assembly (B) as it it not made from Lego parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Assembly A comes from [75103-1: First Order Transporter](https://brickset.com/sets/75103-1/First-Order-Transporter)

[image]

See [instructions 75103-1 page=30](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/6142946.pdf#page=30)

- Assembly C is from [page 65](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/6142946.pdf#page=65) 
  (thanks @ LegoSonicBoy)

Comment: Which non-Lego parts do you see in assembly C?

Comment: @henrik; missing logo on the right plate (could be the lightning of the photo)

Comment: @Syberion: It's the lighting. I can just about make out pixels of shadows of the logo on the studs. Assembly C is from the same set - you can see it in page 65 of the instructions.